# Writing Application to hide time in the notificationbar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-notification-bar

I want to write myself an Application to hide the time in the notificationbar and i´m lookin out for some way to do so!

I want it to look like this for example, just not visible:

[image]

Do you have any hints how i can accomplish the time in the notificationbar gone?

Thanks in advance, i know this isnt a very specific question but i´dont look for a specific answer either!

EDIT: Currently i´m using the app [super status bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firezenk.ssb&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5maXJlemVuay5zc2IiXQ..) to hide the time but unfortunally it delivers a lot more than i want. Within the alternative status bar i just set the fontcolor of the time to black. When this app can do it there has to be some kind of way to accomplish the time not visible or gone right!?

Comment: personal quirk, just dont wanna know how late it is when i use my phone! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can't accomplish that with a widget, and you can't do that without actually modifying the OS itself, and building a custom ROM. There is no way for you to override the system part of the notification bar as a third-party application.